# Error with "$" when using OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#, excel, oledbdataadapter

I seem to be getting the error

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: '$' is not a valid name.  Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."

My sheet name does not have a '$' in it so it must be some problem with the syntax I'm not sure what the problem is so any help or insight on why this error is occurring and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    string form = comboBox1.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + form + "$]", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: I know but its part of the syntax when selecting a sheet, if you take it out it doesn't work either.

Comment: whats ur sheet name?

Comment: The sheet name is RXRFXS2

Comment: try this `string form = "RXRFXS2"; string query = String.Format("select * from [{0}$]", form);OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn);` check.

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: do u have any column name with $?

Comment: No there was no column with $

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82031/discussion-between-sachu-and-brandan-b).